# Column order doesn't change in DataTables plugin

Tags: javascript, datatables

I wanted to reverse column on export data from DataTables. I look for method to do it and finally ended up with this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var arrayCol = new Array();
            var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                initComplete:function (  ) {
                    var len = this.api().columns().count();
                    var array =  Array.from(Array(len).keys())
                    arrayCol = array.reverse();
                  },
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                     exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)',
                             orthogonal: 'export'
                             
                        }
                },
               {
                   extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                   orientation: 'landscape',
                   pageSize: 'A4',
                    exportOptions: {
                
                    columns: arrayCol, // this doesn't work
                     //columns:[5,4,3,2,1,0], //this work
                        orthogonal: 'export'
                    
                   }
                    
                    
               }
    ]
                });
        });
```

The `var arrayCol` when debugging has values but when exporting to PDF the PDF doesn't have any columns.

Maybe it doesn't assign to columns or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to reverse each individual row array, as you are exporting the data. You can use `exportOptions.rows` to do this.

You also need to reverse the headers, which can be done using `exportOptions.format.heeader`. In this case, you only get access to one header field at a time, so there is a bit more work needed to build a reversed array of header values and then access each index location in that array:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      { 
        extend: 'pdf',
        text: 'To PDF',
        exportOptions: {
          rows: function ( idx, data, node ) {
            return data.reverse();
          },
          format: {
            header: function ( data, idx, node ) {
              var headers = $('#example').DataTable().table().header();
              var reversedHeaders = headers.innerText.split('\t').reverse();
              return reversedHeaders[idx];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  } );

} );
```

References:

- [export options](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData())
- [row selectors - function](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector#Function)

Comment: there is a problem in export excel because operation columns i try to remove it using columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)', but it's not work well

Comment: Sorry - I am not sure what that means. Can you clarify? Or maybe create a new question where you can explain the problem in more detail, with an example?

Comment: i will make new question

Comment: i add question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896587/datatable-remove-column-on-export-to-pdf-and-excel