# datatable remove column on export to pdf and excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i have a problem when remove column before export to pdf,excel.
and second problem that because of this column the reverse of column doesn't work right
here is the code i use

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            var arrayCol = new Array();
            var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                dom: 'B<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>',
                initComplete:function (  ) {
                    var len = this.api().columns().count();
                    var array =  Array.from(Array(len).keys());
                    arrayCol = array.reverse();
                  },
            buttons: [
      { 
        extend: 'pdf',
        text: 'To PDF',
        exportOptions: {
          rows: function ( idx, data, node ) {
            return data.reverse();
          },
          format: {
          columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)', 
            header: function ( data, idx, node ) {
              var headers = $('#example').DataTable().table().header();
              var reversedHeaders = headers.innerText.split('\t').reverse();
              return reversedHeaders[idx];
            }
          }
        }
      },
               { 
        extend: 'excel',
        text: 'exel',
        exportOptions: {
        columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)', 
          rows: function ( idx, data, node ) {
            return data.reverse();
          },
          format: {
            header: function ( data, idx, node ) {
              var headers = $('#example').DataTable().table().header();
              var reversedHeaders = headers.innerText.split('\t').reverse();
              return reversedHeaders[idx];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
                });
        });
```

and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xekv5Lwh/4/) is live example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the approach used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68885988/12567365) to handle the extra requirement for suppressing one or more columns that you do not want to export.

Your use of the columns selector works well:

```
columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)
```

For building a list of the headers we want to export, the `initComplete` function can be used (so we only perform this process once).

We can also use the `initComplete` function to build an array of column indexes that we do *not* want to export:

```js
var ignorePositions = []; // column indexes of data NOT to be exported
var reversedHeaders = []; // with "not-export" headings removed
```

The function:

```js
initComplete:function (  ) {
  var thead = $( '#example' ).DataTable().table().header();
  var tds = $( thead ).find( 'th' ).each(function( index ) {
    if ( ! $( this ).hasClass('not-export-col') ) {
      reversedHeaders.push( $( this ).text() );
    } else {
      ignorePositions.push(index);
    }
  });
  reversedHeaders.reverse(); // to give us the export order we want
  ignorePositions.reverse(); // reversed for when we splice() - see below
}
```

The above code populates two arrays:

- `reversedHeaders` - containing a list (in reverse) of the headings for those columns we will export.
- `ignorePositions` - containing a list of column indexes to be ignored. In our example, the only such column is the final one (index 6).

Then we can use the above arrays in our modified `exportOptions` code:

```
exportOptions: {
  rows: function ( idx, data, node ) {
    var keepRowData = [];
    // we splice to remove those data fields we do not want to export:
    ignorePositions.forEach(idx => data.splice(idx, 1) );
      return data.reverse();
  },
  columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)',
  format: { 
    header: function ( data, idx, node ) {
      return reversedHeaders[idx];
    }
  }
}
```

The only tricky part is the need to use `splice` to directly alter the original `data` array. This cuts out each unwanted element from the original data array, without creating a new data array.

Putting it all together:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <!-- buttons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th class="not-export-col">opr</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
<!--
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th class="not-export-col">opr</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
-->
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
            <td><a href="www.google.com"><i class="wb-edit"></i></a></td>
          </tr>
<!--
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
            <td><a href="www.google.com"><span class="iconify" data-icon="fa:edit"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$4,800</td>
            <td><a href="www.google.com"><span class="iconify" data-icon="fa:edit"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
            <td><a href="www.google.com"><span class="iconify" data-icon="fa:edit"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
            <td><a href="www.google.com"><span class="iconify" data-icon="fa:edit"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
            <td><a href="www.google.com"><span class="iconify" data-icon="fa:edit"></span></a></td>
          </tr>
-->
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var ignorePositions = []; // column indexes of data NOT to be exported
  var reversedHeaders = []; // with "not-export" headings removed

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'B<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>',
    initComplete:function (  ) {
      var thead = $( '#example' ).DataTable().table().header();
      var tds = $( thead ).find( 'th' ).each(function( index ) {
        if ( ! $( this ).hasClass('not-export-col') ) {
          reversedHeaders.push( $( this ).text() );
        } else {
          ignorePositions.push(index);
        }
      });
      reversedHeaders.reverse(); // to give us the export order we want
      ignorePositions.reverse(); // reversed for when we splice() - see below
    },
    buttons: [
      { 
        extend: 'pdf',
        text: 'To PDF',
        exportOptions: {
          rows: function ( idx, data, node ) {
            var keepRowData = [];
            // we splice to remove those data fields we do not want to export:
            ignorePositions.forEach(idx => data.splice(idx, 1) );
            return data.reverse();
          },
          columns: ':visible:not(.not-export-col)',
          format: { 
            header: function ( data, idx, node ) {
              return reversedHeaders[idx];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  } );
} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The table data, which looks like this[image]:

Is exported to PDF like this:

[image]

---

Final notes:

1. I only implemented the PDF button in the above code. The Excel button code also needs to be added, but should be identical.
2. I commented out the `<tfoot>` section of the HTML table in my code. I think this means you will also need to add a `footer: function() { ... }` to your implementation, to match the `header: function() { ... }` code. I assume that would be as follows (but I did not test this):

```
format: { 
  header: function ( data, idx, node ) {
    return reversedHeaders[idx];
  },
  footer: function ( data, idx, node ) {
    return reversedHeaders[idx];
  }
}
```

---

**Update**

I see the annoying alert. This is caused by my code which changes the length of the data row (when it splices out an element).

A second issue is that once a row has been reversed, it remains reversed - so, on the next export, the exported data is in the wrong order.

To address both of these is messy, and my proposed solution is limited:

**My solution assumes that you only want to hide the final column**.

It also relies on you being able to detect when a row is reversed - and in my case this is done by checking for a specific value in the final location of the row data - again, not a very robust approach - but it is the only approach I can think of right now.

Here is the updated code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var exportPositions = []; // column indexes of data NOT to be exported
  var ignorePositions = []; // column indexes of data NOT to be exported
  var reversedHeaders = []; // with "not-export" headings removed

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'B<"top"iflp<"clear">>rt<"bottom"ip<"clear">>',
    initComplete:function (  ) {
      var thead = $( '#example' ).DataTable().table().header();
      var tds = $( thead ).find( 'th' ).each(function( index ) {
        if ( ! $( this ).hasClass('not-export-col') ) {
          reversedHeaders.push( $( this ).text() );
          exportPositions.push(index);
        } else {
          ignorePositions.push(index);
        }
      });
      reversedHeaders.reverse(); // to give us the export order we want
      reversedHeaders.push('');
      ignorePositions.reverse(); // reversed for when we splice() - see below
    },
    buttons: [
      { 
        extend: 'pdf',
        text: 'To PDF',
        exportOptions: {
          rows: function ( idx, data, node ) {
            if (data[data.length - 1] === '~') {
              data.reverse(); // un-reverse an already reversed record
              data.push(data.splice(0, 1)[0]); // move first element to end of the array
            }
            // we splice to remove those data fields we do not want to export:
            ignorePositions.forEach(idx => {
              data.splice(idx, 1);
            } );
            data.reverse();
            ignorePositions.forEach(idx => {
              data.push('~'); // pad the array back to its original length
            } );
            return data;
          },
          columns: exportPositions, // here we use the array we built earlier
          format: { 
            header: function ( data, idx, node ) {
              return reversedHeaders[idx];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  } );
} );
```

If your actual implementation needs to hide multiple columns then this approach will probably not work for you. If I have any thoughts on a more robust solution, I will update the answer.

Comment: excel in exporting for first time work but for second time doesn't work, and there's annoying alert appear how to solve it

Comment: I see what you mean - I have provided some updates.